# Maintain column of characters when using prop.table

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  sent = letters[1:5],
  n.x = abs(rnorm(5)),
  n.y = abs(rnorm(5))
)
```

If I coerce it to a matrix, and then use `prop.table`:

```
prop.table(data.matrix(data), 2)
```

I get the following:

```
           sent       n.x       n.y
[1,] 0.06666667 0.0948657 0.1665655
[2,] 0.13333333 0.1042308 0.2598814
[3,] 0.20000000 0.3516696 0.2230854
[4,] 0.26666667 0.2617903 0.1438551
[5,] 0.33333333 0.1874436 0.2066125
```

How do I keep the first column as a character vector?

Comment: just did a wee test: as your data become bigger (wider and longer) it is faster and more memory efficient to use `cbind(data[1], lapply(data[-1], prop.table)` I guess as it doesn't create a new matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you actually want is

```
data <- data.frame(
    sent = letters[1:5],
    n.x = abs(rnorm(5)),
    n.y = abs(rnorm(5))
)

cbind(data[1], prop.table(data.matrix(data[-1]), 2))

  sent          n.x        n.y
1    a 0.0004247739 0.17667990
2    b 0.1748003178 0.30665196
3    c 0.1361206704 0.17707674
4    d 0.6359362530 0.25927624
5    e 0.0527179849 0.08031516
```